# Changing theme is not persistent Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I'am changing theme by `ui.setTheme("theme-name")`. It works great until I change the page - then it goes back to the default one. How to make it persistent?

Every page class has `@Theme` annotation with default theme's name taken from Spring's `application.yml`.

Comment: Which version of Vaadin?

Comment: Version I use : 8.5.2.

Comment: Provide further detail by editing your Question rather than as a Comment. Also, you can add the tag for Vaadin 8.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because every time a new page is loaded in the browser (i.e. not only changing from one view to another using e.g. Navigator), a new UI instance is created. That UI instance will use the default theme unless someone has explicitly run `setTheme("some-theme")` again.

There are a couple of different approaches to fixing this depending on how persistent you want the theme to be.

One approach is to add `@PreserveOnRefresh` to your `UI` subclass. This will make the previous UI instance reused when reloading or temporarily navigating to some other site. It will not preserve the UI and the theme setting if the user closes their browser tab and opens a new one later on.

The other approach is that you explicitly store the user's theme selection somewhere and then manually reapply that setting in e.g. `UI.init` or after the user has logged in. The two most obvious candidates for storing this is in a cookie or in the user database.

Comment: Inspired by this question, I created an add-on that automatically stores the theme name in a cookie and uses that setting when opening the application. https://vaadin.com/directory/component/theme-cookie